# Gradle dependency hierarchy in script

Tags: gradle, dependencies

My goal is to print the dependencies of a gradle build including there hierarchy. The idea is to graphically build a dependency graph. The information I need would be the same as when I type gradle dependencies.

How can I achive this? Where do I get the information from, when I create my own task?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this is what you're looking for:

```
project.configurations.compile.resolvedConfiguration.resolvedArtifacts.each {
 println it.name // << the artifact name
 println it.file // << the file reference
}
```

It comes from [How to retrieve a list of actual dependencies (including transitive deps) - Old Forum - Gradle Forums](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/how-to-retrieve-a-list-of-actual-dependencies-including-transitive-deps/6077/4)

Comment: this is what i need

Answer (score 1):

I'm just a gradle newbie, so perhaps there is depth to your question I don't see. Do you mean:

```
> gradle dependencies
:dependencies

------------------------------------------------------------
Root project
------------------------------------------------------------

archives - Configuration for archive artifacts.
No dependencies

compile - Compile classpath for source set 'main'.
\--- commons-collections:commons-collections:3.2

default - Configuration for default artifacts.
\--- commons-collections:commons-collections:3.2

runtime - Runtime classpath for source set 'main'.
\--- commons-collections:commons-collections:3.2

testCompile - Compile classpath for source set 'test'.
+--- commons-collections:commons-collections:3.2
\--- junit:junit:4.+ -> 4.12
     \--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3

testRuntime - Runtime classpath for source set 'test'.
+--- commons-collections:commons-collections:3.2
\--- junit:junit:4.+ -> 4.12
     \--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 4.47 secs
```

This was created from a `build.gradle` file with only these direct dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    compile group: 'commons-collections', name: 'commons-collections', version: '3.2'
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.+'
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is what gradle provides me. However I want to influence the output. Generate a .dot graph. Therefore I need to have a task e.g. "depentenciesAsDOTGraph" which iterates through all those dependencies and print a graph. However I don't know which Objects I need to access to walk through the hierarchy of the dependencies and print htem...

Comment: Perl is your friend if you want to parse the output of `gradle dependencies`! :-)